# IBM Cloud Functions and Node.js: How to get Japan time?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I am writing a Node.js action in IBM Cloud Functions. How to get Japan time? I tried the following code at 6:28 AM Japan time but I got 9:28 PM.

Code:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString({ timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo' }))
```

Output:

```
"2021-10-12T21:28:43.740984Z    stdout: 10/12/2021, 9:28:43 PM"
```

I wonder if it was Sydney time because my namespace is in Sydney. However, It was 8:28 AM in Sydney, so I'm confusing.

Comment: Could you add more details to your question? Would the printed time match UTC?

Comment: Oh that's right. It was UTC. Thanks to your comment, I found a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no first argument.

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('ja-JP', { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo' }))
```